# Concurrency Level in ConcurrentHashMap in Java

Tags: concurrenthashmap

Can anyone help me in this scenario: 
There are several threads reading & only one thread updating a HashMap, should I use  ConcurrentHashMap and set concurrencyLevel as 1(since default value of concurrencyLevel is 16), or just use HashMap without synchronized directly?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the question about concurrency level for now, the general rule of thumb is that if you want to safely share mutable state (reading & writing from multiple threads) you need some form of synchronization.

Java gives you a lot of ways to accomplish this:

1. The `synchronized` keyword
2. One of the threadsafe collections, like [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)
3. The various [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) implementations
4. One of the synchronized collection wrappers (e.g.
   [`Collections.synchronizedMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-)) - *although I cannot think of a situation where you would actually want to use these.*

From what we know of your use case (which isn't a lot), the best "out-of-the-box" option would be to use `ConcurrentHashMap`. It doesn't require you to manually synchronize and if you use it correctly it can make your code threadsafe.

Based on the documentation it seems you would want to set the `concurrencyLevel` argument to `1`, but these are things that you can *and should* test. Depending on how much contention you actually have, it may not matter a whole lot.